# Textarea input field is not being captured

Tags: html, text-editor

I have the following input textarea field inside a form:

```
<textarea name="desc" class="summernote">
 Default text
</textarea>
```

Now I am inspecting after submitting the form and got as follows:

```
Array ( [desc] => Default text )
```

But when I change textarea input field value and submit again I am reeving the same data. Whats wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 0):

please replace your code with this code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="desc" class="summernote">Default text</textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitform">
        </form>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.submitform').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var check = $(".summernote").val();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not encouraged, please provide some information why and how your code solves the problem.

Comment: @Frieder basically this code will provide you current data only and for that I have added preventDefault and after that fetching the textarea value.